# "Hi-fi" is to "High fidelity" as "Wi-fi" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

“Hi-fi” is to “High fidelity” as “Wi-fi” is to what? I thought to refer "Wi-fi" to “wireless fidelity”, but it seem to have no precise meaning.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#The_name

Comment: [wifi](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Wi-Fi?q=wifi). Please refer to dictionaries before asking meaning questions. If the dictionary doesn't satisfy you, please explain why in your question.

Comment: Thank you Dwight and Matt! So, wi-fi does not mean 'wireless fidelity', it means hi-fi with one letter changed!

Comment: No! It is the brand name of IEEE 802.11b Direct Sequence. The *Fi* doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Yes, @Matt! I agree, it seems more plausible that "wireless fidelity" would, if it meant anything at all, refer to a spouse who remained faithful even when not attached to electrodes! Haha!

Comment: My first name is "David". I'm told it means "beloved". But it's just my name. Names, when used as names, don't have meanings beyond referring to the things they name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has the answer:

"The name
The term Wi-Fi, first used commercially in August 1999, was coined by a brand-consulting firm called Interbrand Corporation. The Wi-Fi Alliance had hired Interbrand to determine a name that was "a little catchier than 'IEEE 802.11b Direct Sequence'". [Belanger also stated that Interbrand invented Wi-Fi as a play on words with Hi-Fi (high fidelity), and also created the Wi-Fi logo.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#The_name)"

Comment: And *Hi-Fi* itself originated in the 50s phrase "high fidelity", and then signified "cutting-edge sound recording and playback technology"; but by the 60s it actually *meant* little more than "playback system a cut above the lowest consumer grade".

Comment: Yes, @StoneyB! Hi-fi has existed since 1934. The Germans, as you say, tried to standardise the meaning of the term hi-fi back in the *sixties*, but it didn't really catch on. It was just a general term of approval that then became interchangeable with cassette player because everybody claimed to be highly faithful.